# ERC 20 Remix Gas Allowance ERROR

Tags: contract-development, remix, erc-20, gas, error

I have this basic contract made on Openzeppelin Wizard, but everytime I try to deploy it on Mainnet i get the same error " exceeds gas allowance". I succesfully deployed it on Goerli. I've tried everything online but can t solve it.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.9.0/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import"@openzeppelin/contracts@4.9.0/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";

contract Muiasa is ERC20, ERC20Burnable {
    constructor() ERC20("Muiasa", "MUI") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000000000 * 10 ** decimals());
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: how much are you allowing for contract deployment on mainnet ? errors on deployment will trigger a high gas usage and will output such errors, so be sure of the deployment script

Comment: 3Million , the recommended gas limit by remix

Comment: the problem is , even if i change it to 30 million it still gets the same error